# Error in ubuntu while starting the machine recovery journey

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have installed ubuntu on virtual machine. it was working perfectly fine from last two month but last night. I enabled the hype v after that my virtual machine is not working fine . now i disable the hype-v but virtual machine is not working still. I received this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feKKr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps -

1. Turn off the windows feature.
2. Untick the hyper-v.
3. Run virtual machine as administration.

Maybe these steps will solve your problems.